# How to create shared Google Compute Engine images?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, disk-image

In the past I've been using `gcimagebundle` to create an image from an existing GCE instance, that I can later upload to Cloud Storage.

Since the tool been deprecated, I wonder if there is an alternative *easy* method to create GCE images?

To clarify: I want to create images that are publicly shared (with any GCP user/project). This to distribute easy to start images of the [Redash](https://redash.io) project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer versions of [Packer](http://packer.io/) added support for [Google Compute Export](https://www.packer.io/docs/post-processors/googlecompute-export.html) Post-Processor, which makes it easy to create a public image.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new IAM role launched recently which allow you to share private images across Projects using Image User role. However, this IAM role is in beta release and is not covered by any SLA. You can refer to [this link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/sharing-images-across-projects) for more information.

Comment: It seems that this requires giving permission to specific projects. I want to create public image (I updated my question to better explain my use case).

Comment: compute.imageUser IAM role provide the user in another project access to your private images. This seems to be the easiest option available to share the images across projects with different users. With that said, you can still export images to GCS and share them, detailed steps are documented on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image).

Answer (score 0):

```
https://github.com/khushbuparakh/gcp/blob/master/instance.py
```

I have written this script.  You can use this. It creates a bucket. Upload your private file to the bucket. Create an image using that file and spin up an instance with your private image. Not that file you are uploading needs to be compressed with tar.gz and con